# $ \ddot{y}+k^{2} \cdot y=0$: Book solution: $y_b(t)=A \cosh (k t)+B \sinh (k t)$ Mine: $y(t)=A e^{i k t}+B e^{-i k t}$. How to calculat $y_b$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics

My solution:
$$
y^{\prime \prime}(t)=-y \cdot k^{2} \Leftrightarrow \ddot{y}+k^{2} \cdot y=0 \\
\Rightarrow \lambda^{2}+k^{2}=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}= \pm i k \\
y(t)=A e^{i k t}+B e^{-i k t}$$

with $A, B \in \mathbb{R} $.

Books solution: $$ y_b(t)=A \cos (k t)+B \sin (k t) $$

The index $b$ just refers to the solution given in the book.

Both solution are correct but how do you calculate the $y_b$ solution?

Edit: There seems to be a printing error in the book, I corrected the function $y_b$. The question remains the same.

Comment: Are you sure you're solving the same equation? The book's solution is for $\ddot{y} - k^2 y = 0$

Comment: If the differential equation is right, the book solution should be $$y_b=A\cos(kt)+B\sin(kt)$$So regular trigonometric functions, not hyperbolic ones.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It is: $\ddot{y}+k^{2} \cdot y=0$

Comment: Then the book is wrong.

Comment: They probably made a printing error. I still don't get, how one gets $y_b=A\cos(kt)+B\sin(kt)$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are in fact complex numbers, not real.

Comment: Oh, than I made a wrong assumption, question is answered